# Dynamically get a list of keys to access the deepest non-dict values in a nest dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary where I want to return a dynamic list of the keys that would access any non-dict values. I do not know the structure of the dictionary beforehand and nesting could go n-levels.

```
{
    "parent": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": {
            "nested": "first"
        }
    }
}
```

From this dictionary, I want to return the following list of lists:

```
[
    ["parent", "a"],
    ["parent", "b", "nested"]
]
```

I plan to use this list with `functools` and `reduce` to get specific values out of the dictionary to build a new dictionary. I've tried a recursion function to lop through the dictionary items and check for `isinstance(value, dict)`, but I'm having issues keeping the path together. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the paths of the sub-dicts generated from recursive calls with the dict values to the keys of the current dict. Since you don't need leaf values, yield an empty list for them:

```
def paths(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        yield from ([k, *p] for k, v in d.items() for p in paths(v))
    else:
        yield []
```

so that:

```
d = {
    "parent": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": {
            "nested": "first"
        }
    }
}
print(list(paths(d)))
```

outputs:

```
[['parent', 'a'], ['parent', 'b', 'nested']]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Q5I8lK

Answer (score 1):

It can be  achievable by recursively traversing the dictionary and keeping track of the keys as you go deeper into the nested dictionaries

```
def find_non_dict_paths(d):
    def _find_paths(d, current_path=None):
        paths = []
        if current_path is None:
            current_path = []

        for key, value in d.items():
            new_path = current_path + [key]

            if isinstance(value, dict):
                paths.extend(_find_paths(value, new_path))
            else:
                paths.append(new_path)

        return paths

    return _find_paths(d)

data = {
    "parent": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": {
            "nested": "first"
        }
    }
}

result = find_non_dict_paths(data)
print(result)
```